# Objective-C equivalent of Java Language Specification or C++ Standard?

Tags: objective-c, standards

What is the Objective-C equivalent of the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) or the [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2914.pdf)?

Is it this:
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html ?

(I'm just looking for an (official) authoritative document which will explain the little nitty-gritties of the language. I'll skip the why for now :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906767/objective-c-standards-document

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Appendix A of the document you linked to is a description of all of the language features, which is the closest we have to a specification (Appendix B used to be a grammar specification, but they've clearly removed that from the later versions of the document).

There has never been a standardisation of Objective-C and it's always been under the control of a single vendor - initially StepStone, then NeXT Computer licensed it (and ultimately bought the IP) and finally Apple consumed NeXT Software. I expect there's little motivation to go through the labourious process of standardisation on Apple's part, especially as there are no accusations of ObjC being an anticompetitive platform which standardisation could mitigate.

Comment: The Appendix A was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @porneL: I didn't believe you so I looked. Exceptions and @synchronize are in the appendix, and so are protocols. Look in the "compiler directives" section.

Comment: OK, nevermind. I found old version of Apple's docs that has it (http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOPandObjC1/OOPandObjC1.pdf) [10th edit: I'm blogging in this comment ;)]

Answer (score 12):

There is none.  The link you provided is the only 'official' documentation, which is essentially a prose description, and not a rigorous language specification.  Apple employees suggest that this is sufficient for most purposes, and if you require something more formal you should file a bug report (!).  Sadly, the running joke is the Objective-C standard is defined by whatever the compiler is able to compile.

Many consider Objective-C to be either a "strict superset" or "superset" of C.  IMHO, for 'classic' Objective-C (or, Objective-C 1.0), I would consider this to be a true statement.  In particular, I'm not aware of any Objective-C language addition that does not map to an equivalent "plain C" statement.  In essence, this means the Objective-C additions are pure syntactic sugar, and one can use the C standard in effect to reason about the nitty gritty.  I'm not convinced that this is entirely true for Objective-C 2.0 with GC enabled.  This is because pointers to GC managed memory need to be handled specially (the compiler must insert various barriers depending on the particulars of the pointer).  Since the GC pointer type qualifiers, such as `__strong`, are implemented as `__attribute__(())` inside `gcc`, this means that `void *p;` and `void __strong *p;` are `similarly qualified pointers` according to the C99 standard.  The problems that this can cause, and even the ability to write programs that operate in a deterministic manner, are either self evident or not (consult your local language lawyer or compiler writer for more information).

Another problem that comes up from time to time is that the C language has continued to evolve relative to the Objective-C language.  Objective-C dates back to the mid 1980's, which is pre-ANSI-C standard time.  Consider the following code fragement:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *array = mutableArray;
```

This is legal Objective-C code as defined by the official prose description of the language.  This is also one of the main concepts behind Object Oriented programming.  However, when one considers those statements couched from the perspective of "strict superset of C99", one runs in to a huge problem.  In particular, this violates C99's `strict aliasing rules`.  A standards grade language specification would help clarify the treatment and behavior of such conflicts.  Unfortunatly, because no such document exists, there can be much debate over such details, and ultimately result in bugs in the compiler.  This has resulted in a bug in `gcc` that dates all the way back to version 3.0 ([gcc bug #39753](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39753)).

Answer (score 1):

Apple's document is about the best you're going to get. Like many other languages, Objective-C doesn't have a formal standard or specification; rather, it is described mostly by its canonical implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Further resources include:

- The [Objective-C Language and GNUstep Base Library Programming Manual](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual.pdf).
- The [NeXT developers library](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/ObjectivCBook.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Apple (now) using clang of the llvm.org project.

Some of the language elements are defined in this context

e.g.  Objective-C literals --> http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

But i didn't found a clear overview of all elements.

--- updated --

The source of Apples clang is available (as open source) here:
http://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/